Android Fragment layout starts below AppBarLayout
I am using navigation drawer, navigation component and custom toolbar all together. When i come to my home fragment, there is no problem. It looks as it's supposed to be. Like :

There is no space between my fragment and toolbar (as you can see with green line) but when i navigate to another fragment through navigation drawer it looks like this :

There is no margin or anything else in my other fragment. Already i have many more fragments and in every fragment (except home fragment), it happens. Any way to fix it? My MainActivity xml file here :
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbarLay"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/toolbarColor"
                android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
                app:popupTheme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light"
                app:titleTextColor="@color/transparent" />

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

        <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
            android:id="@+id/fragmentContainerView"
            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:defaultNavHost="true"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbarLay"
            app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:backgroundTint="?attr/navBackgroundColor"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
        app:itemIconTint="?attr/navIconColor"
        app:itemTextColor="?attr/navTextColor"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/nav_menu" />

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>

